# TSQL Join on Tables with Multiple Counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that I am trying to get 2 different counts from the same data using 2 left joins.

For whatever reason, it is duplicating the data and providing an incorrect result and I am not sure why.

This is the query that I have so far which I thought would be working:

```
DECLARE @locale INT = '14'

SELECT TOP 50
    E.[DepartmentDesc] AS department,
    COUNT(N.[nomineeQID]) AS totalNominations,
    COUNT(S.[subQID]) AS totalSubmissions,
    COUNT(N.[nomineeQID]) + COUNT(S.[subQID]) AS total
FROM 
    employees AS E
LEFT JOIN 
    submissions AS S ON E.[qid] = S.[subQID] AND S.[statusID] = 3
                        AND S.[locationID] = @locale
LEFT JOIN 
    submissions AS N ON E.[qid] = N.[nomineeQID] AND N.[statusID] = 3
                     AND N.[locationID] = @locale
GROUP BY
    E.[DepartmentDesc]
ORDER BY
    totalNominations DESC
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle of the data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e6b5/1

The result should be the following but it is providing skewed numbers:

- Total Nominations should be 3
- Total Submissions should be 2
- Total should be 5

I have a feeling its close but the math is just not cooperating!

Any ideas?

Comment: Check my answer ;) I think it's OK

Comment: I've updated my answer to cut 0 / 0 rows, show sqlfiddle too

Comment: I've updated again my answer about grouped by department desc. show sqlfiddle too ;)

Comment: My fault, I've update again again the sql fiddle and the query, now you'd must not show duplicated rows. Try with a properly data set and then tell me if it's ok ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @locale INT = '14'

select TOP 50 t.department, sum(t.totalSubmissions),
sum(t.totalNominations), sum(t.total)
from 
(SELECT
    E.[DepartmentDesc]    AS department,

    (select COUNT(S.[subQID])
    from submissions AS S
    where E.[qid] = S.[subQID]
    AND S.[statusID] = 3
    AND S.[locationID] = @locale) AS totalSubmissions,

    (select COUNT(N.[nomineeQID])
    from submissions AS N
    where E.[qid] = N.[nomineeQID]
    AND N.[statusID] = 3
    AND N.[locationID] = @locale) AS totalNominations,

    (select COUNT(S.[subQID])
    from submissions AS S
    where E.[qid] = S.[subQID]
    AND S.[statusID] = 3
    AND S.[locationID] = @locale) +
    (select COUNT(N.[nomineeQID])
    from submissions AS N
    where E.[qid] = N.[nomineeQID]
    AND N.[statusID] = 3
    AND N.[locationID] = @locale) AS total  

FROM employees AS E
where exists(
  select 'submission'
  from submissions AS S
  where E.[qid] = S.[subQID]
  AND S.[statusID] = 3
  AND S.[locationID] = @locale
) or
exists(
 select 'nomination'
 from submissions AS N
 where E.[qid] = N.[nomineeQID]
 AND N.[statusID] = 3
 AND N.[locationID] = @locale
 )
) as t
group by t.department
ORDER BY sum(t.totalNominations) DESC
```

Go to [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ae03/9/0)

Comment: This is close however I don't want to include other employees from the employee table that aren't part of this query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ae03/1

Comment: If there is an easy way to groupBy now then this should work perfectly - It is showing the same department multiple times when all of the same depts need to grouped together

Comment: The demo works fine as expected; my code is just returning duplicate departments still; thanks though!

Comment: Strange - I get what seems to be unique departments now but no counts :( so close!

Comment: Strange, because if I load Sql Fiddle there are counts. I've tried with duplicated employee in the same department too. If I can help you tell me

Comment: In the `select` as I had to give the sums an alias to get the data

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a cartesian product for each department.  The simplest fix to your query is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
                    COUNT(DISTINCT N.[nomineeQID]) AS totalNominations,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT S.[subQID])     AS totalSubmissions,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT N.[nomineeQID]) + COUNT(DISTINCT S.[subQID]) AS total
```

A more correct fix is to do the aggregations in subqueries before doing the `join`.

EDIT:

Because of the duplications problem, use `SubmissionId` instead:

```
                    COUNT(DISTINCT N.SubmissionId) AS totalNominations,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT S.SubmissionId)     AS totalSubmissions,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT N.SubmissionId) + COUNT(DISTINCT S.SubmissionId) AS total
```

Comment: The problem though is There is allowed to be duplicates in the submission tables. A person can be nominated multiple times or submit multiple items. Doing distinct wouldn't give me a correct count.